Google-Chrome GPO pin extensions
In the Google-Chrome-GPO-Settings under Extensions -> Extension management settings I put in
{“*”:{“toolbar_pin”:“force_pinned”}}

but the extenshions are still hidden and not pinned.
Where can be the problem?
